# Using Alarm Manager Even If App closed?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm usign an `Alarm Manager` to update a widget with a `Service`. I've two different questions.

First question: I'm calling the service with Alarm Manager's intent. Like this:

```
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));

Long repeat = Long.parseLong(prefs.getString("update_preference", "600"));
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), 1000*repeat, pi);
```

Is it wrong?

It looks and works right. But when I have looked at *working services,* I can't see my service name in the list. Perhaps it's not running as a *single/seperate* service. Just saw application name (not as a service). I'm not sure how to seperate or does it matter?

Another question: Over long time, running application, which controls widgets update, is **closed** somehow (manually or by a task killer). Of course `Alarm Manager` gonna stop and widget's functions gonna stop too. For example button clicking.

But, Twitter solved this problem. While the widget is active, if I close the main application (Twitter) -which controls widget- than click the widget, somehow widget triggering application and it starts again well. So buttons work properly. How is that possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to do `context.startservice` that what the pending intent is for, if you want the service to run right away the first time just set it to run at the current time then set the interval from the current time.

You are also setting 2 different types of repeating when you don't need to `setRepeating` is strict where `setInexact` is not and can be adjusted by the OS when it gets fired hence the inexact in it. You want one or the other not both.

Also those intervals are very small and its going to kill the battery significantly.

It should just be this

```
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Long repeat = Long.parseLong(prefs.getString("update_preference", "600"));
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                      Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), 1000*repeat, pi);
```

Comment: still you dont need the `context.startService` though, the PendingIntent will start the service

Comment: Firstly, my widget fetching data from any server. Are you sure about using service is unnecessary? Should I use update function in Widget class? Can you give example for using. Thank you.

Comment: I am not saying a service is unnecessary I am saying you dont need to start it like you are, the pending intent starts the service when the AlarmManager is fired

Comment: Okay, you're right, that code starts service twice. Just `startService` line is not necessary. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for the next question? If I clear my mind about that one, I'll accept answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I have not done anything with widgets so I cannot answer that question sorry

Answer (score 1):

It's good that your application/service isn't running all the time.
In fact it doesn't need/has to run all the time for updating a widget. If you schedule an Intent with AlarmManager the application will be started when the intent is fired if it has been closed.

Comment: Got it, clear idea. Thank you. But what if the application which holds the alarm manager closed as I told by manually or by some killer?

Comment: AlarmManager is not running inside your application. There isn't any problem if your application is killed because it will be started by OS  when the service intent is launched.

Comment: Okay, you mean when the interval ends, service starts again. But still click events not working if application goes. This is why I should restart service instantly. But dont know how to do it.

Comment: If the click events need the service started is the handler for the click events that has to start the service.

Comment: Any snippet or example please?